# Get doc files from folder and subfolders using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am inserting a bunch of Word documents into one file for post-processing. When all the files are in one folder, I got my script to work. However to make it robust for future work, I'd like to insert Word files from all folders and subfolders (and possible futher subs) from a certain starting point. I followed this Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHJPliWS9FQ to consider all folders and subfolders and of course amended it for my particular use.

```
  Sub CombineDocs()
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox "Opening"
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim foldername As String 'parent folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Show
      On Error Resume Next
      foldername = .SelectedItems(1)
      Err.Clear
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Documents.Add
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Opening text"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.InsertNewPage
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=2).Select

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim file As Scripting.file
    getfolders foldername
  End sub

Sub getfolders(foldername)
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Call pastedoc(foldername)
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub

Sub pastedoc(StartFolderPath as String)
    Dim file As Scripting.file
    Dim subfol As Scripting.folder
    Dim mainfolder As Scripting.folder
    Set mainfolder = fso.GetFolder(StartFolderPath )

    For Each file In mainfolder.Files
    If ((InStr(1, LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file.Path)), "doc", vbTextCompare) > 0) Or _
         (InStr(1, LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file.Path)), "docx", vbTextCompare) > 0)) And _
                (InStr(1, file.Name, "~$") = 0) Then
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:= _
        file.Path _
        , Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
        End If
    Next file

    For Each subfol In mainfolder.SubFolders
        pastedoc subfol.Path
    Next subfol
End Sub
```

A difference between my code and the tutorial's is that I define the parent folder in the main code and the tutorial does it in the sub script. As a result I get an

> 'object required'

error in the 'set mainfolder' line. I tried defining all objects and names between the main code and calling the subs but I still can't get it to work. Any guidance what could fix the code?

Comment: Where is the `End Sub` for `CombineDocs`?  You can move the `Dim fso` and `Set fso` into `pastedoc` and probably be OK.

Comment: I agree, it's because your code can't find `fso`. Either pass that as an argument, as well, or put the declaration and instantiation in `pastedoc`. Also, as commented, you're missing an `End Sub` I edited one in, just before the next `Sub` but you should double-check it.

Comment: By the way, a belated welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  As you may already know, you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50255851/edit) to include more information.

Comment: The end sub was in my code, before the getfolders dub, but I missed it when copying it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: assuming the `End Sub` for `CombineDocs` was after the `getfolders` call, you can:

1. Remove `getfolders` entirely
2. In `CombineDocs`, say `pastedoc foldername` instead of `getfolders foldername`
3. Change the beginning of `pastedoc` to:

   ```
   Sub pastedoc(StartFolderPath as String)
       Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject       ' ** Added
       Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject    ' ** Added

       Dim file As Scripting.file
       Dim subfol As Scripting.folder
       Dim mainfolder As Scripting.folder
       Set mainfolder = fso.GetFolder(StartFolderPath )

       ' ... (everything else the same)
   ```

In general, you need to `Dim` variables either in the `Sub` where they are used, or at the top of your module, outside any subs.  Please put the `Dim`s inside the `Sub`s whenever you can, since that makes your code much easier to change and maintain.

Comment: Got it! Indeed the getfolders sub was unnecessary.